# Value of $a$ for which two integrals are equal

Tags: definite-integrals

Determine $a$ such that $$\int _0 ^a ([\arctan \sqrt {x}]dx=\int _0 ^a  [\frac {\pi}{2}-\arctan\sqrt {x}]dx$$ where $[.] $ is greatest  integer function so i first took the first integral to get integral as $a [\arctan (a)] $ as I think derivative of integer function is 0 as its always an integer. But I dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x}$ is defined for $x\ge 0$, so we need to consider $a\ge 0$ only.

---

- $\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x}$ is an increasing function and

$$0\le \tan^{-1} \sqrt{x} \le \frac{\pi}{2} < 2$$

\begin{align*}
  \left \lfloor \tan^{-1} \sqrt{x} \right \rfloor &=
   \left \{
    \begin{array}{lr}
      0  \, , & 0\le x < \tan^2 1 \\
      1  \, , & x \ge \tan^2 1
  \end{array}
  \right. \\[5pt]
  \int_0^a
  \left \lfloor
    \tan^{-1} \sqrt{x}
  \right \rfloor \, dx &=
  \left \{
    \begin{array}{lr}
      0  \, , & 0\le a < \tan^2 1 \\
      a-\tan^2 1  \, , & a \ge \tan^2 1
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{align*}

---

- $\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x}$ is a decreasing function and

$$0\le \frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x} \le \frac{\pi}{2} < 2$$

\begin{align*}
  \left \lfloor
    \frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x}
  \right \rfloor &=
  \left \{
    \begin{array}{lr}
      1  \, , & 0\le x < \cot^2 1 \\
      0  \, , & x \ge \cot^2 1
    \end{array}
  \right. \\[5pt]
  \int_0^a
  \left \lfloor
    \frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x}
  \right \rfloor \, dx &=
  \left \{
    \begin{array}{lr}
      a  \, , & 0\le a < \cot^2 1 \\
      \cot^2 1  \, , & a \ge \cot^2 1
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{align*}

---

Note that $\cot^2 1 <\tan^2 1$,

$$\int_0^a
  \left \lfloor
    \tan^{-1} \sqrt{x}
  \right \rfloor \, dx =
\int_0^a
  \left \lfloor
    \frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x}
  \right \rfloor \, dx$$

> $$\implies a=0 \quad \text{or} \quad a=\tan^2 1+\cot^2 1$$

Comment: Answer is $\frac {2 (3+cos (4)}{1-cos (4)} $

Comment: \begin{align*}
  \tan^2 1+\cot^2 1 &= \frac{\sin^2 1}{\cos^2 1}+\frac{\cos^2 1}{\sin^2 1} \\
  &= \frac{\sin^4 1+\cos^4 1}{\sin^2 1\cos^2 1} \\
  &= \frac{(\sin^2 1+\cos^2 1)^2-2\sin^2 1 \cos^2 1}{\sin^2 1\cos^2 1} \\
  &= \frac{1^2-\dfrac{\sin^2 2}{2}}{\dfrac{\sin^2 2}{4}} \\
  &= \frac{4-2\sin^2 2}{\sin^2 2} \\
  &= \frac{4-(1-\cos 4)}{\dfrac{1-\cos 4}{2}} \\
  &= \frac{2(3+\cos 4)}{1-\cos 4}
\end{align*}